# How to code acquire-processing-release of a pool in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to realize a common function like AOP in java. For example, I have a redis pool, acquire-processing-release is something like this:

```
public class JedisInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor{

@Inject private Session<Jedis> session;

@Override
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    if(!session.isClosed()) return invocation.proceed();
    try {
        //acquire connection from pool
        session.start();
        return invocation.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if(!session.isClosed()) {
            //always release connection no matter there's exception or not.
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I need a same function in nodejs, and I'm referring async, but still frustrating. Here's nodejs code:

```
var pool = require('generic-pool');

var redis = require("redis");

var async = require('async');

//Redis pool
var redisPool = pool.Pool({
    name: 'redis',
    create: function(callback) {
        var connection = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1', {});
        callback(null, connection);
    },
    destroy: function(connection) {
        connection.quit();
    },
    max: 5,
    min: 2,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
    log: false
});

module.exports = {
    redis: function(fn) {
        //How to code here by using async ?
    }
}
```

Then I can use this function in somewhere like bellowed, and need not to worry about the connection handling.

```
var value = Utils.redis(function(redis){
    return redis.get('something')
});
```

Comment: The `redis` module on npm does pipelining automatically, so using a pool really shouldn't be necessary. What use case do you have that requires a pool for redis in node?

Comment: @mscdex pipelining automatically is great! I want to use a common method to manage redis connection cycle, then I could use this method anywhere. Of course I could discard pool by using another way. I just want to manage connection cycle.